# Overriding a package function inherited by another package

Tags: r, namespaces, package, knitr

I am trying to override the `tidy.source` function of the `knitr` package. The problem is that `tidy.source` is defined in the `formatR` package, which is imported by the `knitr` package.
If I run:

`get("tidy.source", envir=asNamespace("knitr"))`

I get the original code. 
So I am tempted to override `tidy.source` with:

`assignInNamespace ("tidy.source", function()print("My tidy.source"),  "knitr")`,

but I get:

`Error in bindingIsLocked(x, ns) : no binding for "tidy.source"`.

In fact `tidy.source` is defined in `formatR` and inherited by `knitr`.  With:

`assignInNamespace ("tidy.source", function()print("My tidy.source"),  "formatR")`

everything is apparently smooth, but checking again `get("tidy.source", envir=asNamespace("knitr"))` shows that inside `knitr` nothing has changed.

Any help?

#### EDIT:

This question is partly obsolete due to the new development release of *knitr/formatR*. Many thanks to Yihui for noticing this discussion and for deciding to update his package. See:

https://github.com/yihui/formatR/commit/6f70360f359caa8d2bb33190a1c89530defb0e98

I can definitely switch from *Sweave* to *knitr*.

The general question concerning the overriding of an imported package function remains anyway open. Since it is not related to *knitr/formatR* package anymore, I restate it in more general terms.

Suppose you have a package *main* importing the package *imp*. If you load the former, `"package:main"` shows in the list of the attached packages and both `"main"` and `"sub"` show among the names of the loaded namespaces.

Assume that *main* imports the exported *sub* function *exp.sub.func*, which calls in turns the non-exported *sub* function *prv.sub.func*.  If you want to change/customise *exp.sub.func* with your *exp.sub.func.mod*, you may think of using:

```
assign("exp.sub.func", exp.sub.func.mod, asNamespace ("sub"))
```

As a result, by running `sub::exp.sub.func` you will get your patched version (that is *exp.sub.func.mod*).
Unfortunately, as far as your *exp.sub.func.mod* keeps on relying on *prv.sub.func*, you get the error:

```
Error in [...] : object 'prv.sub.func' not found
```

In fact:

```
environment(sub::exp.sub.func)
```

returns now: `<environment: R_GlobalEnv>` while it was `<environment: namespace:sub>` before patching.

The question is: *how to move the patched function to the proper namespace*?

To implement the problem above you can use whatever packages of course; in my case I used *knitr* and *formatR* as main and imported namespace and *tidy.source()* as patched function.

Comment: Why are you trying to overwrite `tidy.source`?

Comment: I recently needed to do something similar, and formatted it as follows:  `assignInNamespace("grid.curve", grid.curve, ns = "grid")`.  When I ran this command, my revised `grid.curve` had already been sourced into the workspace.  This is a slightly different specification than you used, though to me it looks like yours should work too.  But, I was not working in an inherited environment.

Comment: @mnel This is from Google guidelines for comments: 

> Short comments can be placed after code preceded by two spaces, #, and then one space.
http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/google-r-style.html#comments
It is very common comment practice too, but inline comments after arguments don’t work with “formatR”.

Comment: @BryanHanson
I actually did like you. `function()print("My tidy.source"),’ is intended only to make the code self-contained.

Comment: It might be worth raising an issue on the `formatR` or `knitr` pages regarding changing the `tidying` function or the style of formatting.

Comment: @mnel: Someone did this already, but the answer was disarmingly. "[T]o document function arguments [...] roxygen2 may be a better way to go" https://github.com/yihui/formatR/issues/15

Comment: You could always just use tidy=FALSE and then it won't change your formatting at all

Comment: @antonjo If it is a feature request and I do not know how to do it, I will not do it, but if you already know how to do it, it is another story. I'll be happy to see what you have got as the patched version of `tidy.source()`. `formatR` is hack, and you are hacking at a hack... :)

Comment: @Yihui: Actually I am new to _knitr_/_formatR_. I started with it and I ended up with a more general R language issue. Anyway I will try to give some ideas in a next answer.
Dason: This is what I am doing now, but maybe we can find an even better way))

Comment: Since it's not a knitr problem anymore, have you ever find a solution to override the environment for the patched function yet? I am really interested in this. @antonio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the function in the **formatR** namespace doesn't change what **knitr** uses because **knitr** is already loaded.  So, you could unload and reload it.

```
assignInNamespace("tidy.source", function()print("My tidy.source"), "formatR")
detach('package:knitr', unload=TRUE)
library(knitr)
get("tidy.source", envir=asNamespace("knitr"))
#function()print("My tidy.source")
```

Comment: After trial and error, I am able to have a patched _tidy.source_ shared by _knitr_ and _formatR_, but I have still difficulties in dealing with non-exported _formatR_ functions. I am adding an answer to explain my steps.

Comment: thank you so much @GSee!!! You saved me!! It is sooo f***ed up that this is necessary in R! It's such a trap, so contra-intuitive! I could be debugging this for hours... thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

If all you want is comments after function arguments, I have [added](https://github.com/yihui/formatR/commit/6f70360f359) the support in the [development version](https://github.com/yihui/formatR/), and you can [install it from Github](http://yihui.name/formatR/).

Normally it is a bad idea to modify packages using `assignInNamespace()`, as its documentation shows.

Comment: just FYI, the new version is on CRAN now.

Answer (score 0):

I am perhaps *close* to a solution but I have to deal with non-exported *formatR* functions. In fact the original *tidy.source* code, and therefore the patched version, has calls to non-exported package functions, e.g. `reflow_comments`.

To illustrate the problem and the step I followed, let's start with a test patched *tidy.source* calling a private  *formatR* function.

```
### Listing 1 - Modified tidy.source             

tidy.source.mod=function (source, output, text){ 
  #Print body first line of reflow_comments      
  head(reflow_comments,1)                        
}
```

`source, output, text`  parameters are necessary as passed by *knit* used ahead.

Now I can patch the *tidy.source* with *tidy.source.mod*:

```
### Listing 2 - Patch tidy.source                       

## General clean up                                     
if("knitr" %in% loadedNamespaces() ) detach('package:knitr', unload=TRUE)
if("formatR" %in% loadedNamespaces() ) detach('package:formatR', unload=TRUE)
if(exists("tidy.source"))rm(tidy.source)                
library("formatR")                                      

## Info                                                 
environment(tidy.source )                               
# <environment: namespace:formatR>                      
environment(formatR::tidy.source )                      
# <environment: namespace:formatR>                      

## Change tidy.source with tidy.source.mod              
unlockBinding("tidy.source", env=as.environment("package:formatR"))
assign("tidy.source", tidy.source.mod, envir=as.environment("package:formatR"))
lockBinding("tidy.source", env=as.environment("package:formatR"))
unlockBinding("tidy.source", env=asNamespace ("formatR"))
assign("tidy.source", tidy.source.mod, asNamespace ("formatR") )
environment(tidy.source)= asNamespace( "formatR" )      
lockBinding("tidy.source", env=asNamespace ("formatR"))
```

We can check the results:

```
### Listing 3 - Check results                                                  

getAnywhere(tidy.source)                                                       
# A single object matching 'tidy.source' was found                             
# It was found in the following places                                         
#   .GlobalEnv                                                                 
#   package:formatR                                                            
#   namespace:formatR                                                          
# with value                                                                   

# function (){                                                                 
#   head(reflow_comments,1)                                                    
# }                                                                            
# <environment: namespace:formatR>                                             

tidy.source()                                                                  
# 1 function (text, idx = grepl("^\\\\s*#+", text), width = getOption("width"))
```

Apparently *tidy.source* was correctly substituted with *tidy.source.mod*; namespaces were updated so *tidy.source* has access to (the first line of) non-exported  `reflow_comments` function.

To deal with *knitr* we need also a file to knit, here I use a text string for simplicity.

```
### Listing 4 - Sample file/text to knit

library("knitr") 

text="           
\\documentclass{article}
\\begin{document}

<<comme, include=TRUE>>=
print('hello')   
@                

\\end{document}  
"
```

Is *knitr* able to see the patched *tidy.source*? We can check this with the help of R *debug*.

```
debug(knit)                                   
knit(text=text) #will enter debug session (prompt s'd be like 'Browse[2]>')
# debugging in: knit(text = text)             
# debug: {                                    
# knit body, very long, omitted               
# }                                           
tidy.source #command given inside the debug session
# function (){                                
#   head(reflow_comments,1)                   
# }                                           
tidy.source() # :-( reflow_comments is not accessible
Q  #quit debug session                        

undebug(knit)
```

Unfortunately from *knit* the patched *tidy.source* is visible, but it can't access non-exported *formatR* functions, which for *knit* is normally possible via the non-patched *tidy.source*.

Here some hints may be that `formatR::tidy.source()` doesn't work either:

```
formatR::tidy.source()
# Error in head(reflow_comments, 1) (from #2) : object 'reflow_comments' not found
```

The environment of *namespace:formatR* is:

```
environment(formatR::tidy.source )
# <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
```

That was `<environment: namespace:formatR>` before patching (see info in Listing 2). While `environment(tidy.source )` was easily reset when patching, for *namespace:formatR* we get an error:

```
environment(formatR::tidy.source )=asNamespace( "formatR" )
# Error in environment(formatR::tidy.source) = asNamespace("formatR") :
#  object 'formatR' not found
```

I am still searching....

Comment: Antonio - did you ever find a solution to this? It's just that I am trying to do something similar with another package...

Comment: @TomWenseleers: I came very close, but, after the patch by the author Yihui, I stopped investigating. Maybe now with R 3.0 things are easier.

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible buggy attempt to allow inline comments after function arguments by `tidy.source` function included in the *formatR* package.

```
## ============ Possible (wrong?) ideas on inline comments ============

  tidy.source.mod=  function (source = "clipboard", keep.comment = getOption("keep.comment",
    TRUE), keep.blank.line = getOption("keep.blank.line", TRUE),
    keep.space = getOption("keep.space", FALSE), replace.assign = getOption("replace.assign",
        FALSE), left.brace.newline = getOption("left.brace.newline",
        FALSE), reindent.spaces = getOption("reindent.spaces",
        4), output = TRUE, text = NULL, width.cutoff = getOption("width"),
    ...)
{     
    if (is.null(text)) {
        if (source == "clipboard" && Sys.info()["sysname"] ==
            "Darwin") {
            source = pipe("pbpaste")
        }
        text = readLines(source, warn = FALSE)
    } 
    if (length(text) == 0L || all(grepl("^\\s*$", text))) {
        if (output)
            cat("\n", ...)
        return(list(text.tidy = "", text.mask = ""))
    } 
    text.lines = text
    if (keep.comment) {
        if (!keep.space)
            text.lines = gsub("^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$",
                "", text.lines)
        head.comment = grepl("^[[:space:]]*#", text.lines)
        if (any(head.comment)) {
            text.lines[head.comment] = gsub("\"", "'", text.lines[head.comment])
        }
        if (!keep.space) {
            head.comment = head.comment & !grepl("^\\s*#+'",
                text.lines)
            text.lines = reflow_comments(text.lines, head.comment,
                width.cutoff)
            head.comment = grepl("^[[:space:]]*#", text.lines)
        }
        text.lines[head.comment] = sprintf("invisible(\"%s%s%s\")",
            begin.comment, text.lines[head.comment], end.comment)
        blank.line = grepl("^[[:space:]]*$", text.lines)
        if (any(blank.line) && keep.blank.line) {
            else.line = grep("^[[:space:]]*else(\\W|)", text.lines)
            for (i in else.line) {
                j = i - 1
                while (blank.line[j]) {
                  blank.line[j] = FALSE
                  j = j - 1
                  warning("removed blank line ", j, " (you should not put an 'else' in a separate line!)")
                }
            }
            text.lines[blank.line] = sprintf("invisible(\"%s%s\")",
                begin.comment, end.comment)
        }
        text.lines = mask_inline(text.lines)
    } 
    #modified code
    ic=grepl( "%InLiNe_IdEnTiFiEr%", text.lines)
    text.lines[ic]=substr(text.lines[ic], 1, nchar(text.lines[ic])-1)
    text.lines[ic]=  paste0(text.lines[ic], "%InLiNe_IdEnTiFiEr_mod%\"")
    #end modified code
    text.mask = tidy_block(text.lines, width.cutoff, replace.assign)
    text.tidy = if (keep.comment)
        unmask.source(text.mask)
    else text.mask
    text.tidy = reindent_lines(text.tidy, reindent.spaces)
    if (left.brace.newline)
        text.tidy = move_leftbrace(text.tidy, reindent.spaces)
    #modified code
    text.tidy= unlist(sapply(text.tidy, strsplit, "%InLiNe_IdEnTiFiEr_mod%", USE.NAMES=FALSE))
    #end modified code
    if (output)
        cat(paste(text.tidy, collapse = "\n"), "\n", ...)
    invisible(list(text.tidy = text.tidy, text.mask = text.mask))
}     
## ====================================================


## ============ Implementation ============

## Clean-up
if("formatR" %in% loadedNamespaces() ) detach('package:formatR', unload=TRUE)
if(exists("tidy.source"))rm(tidy.source)
library("formatR")


## String with inline comments after arguments
text.input="paste(1 # comm
   ,7)
"     
## The same in vector format
text.input=strsplit(text.input, "\n")[[1]]

## Implementation without patch
tidy.source(text=text.input) #newline removed with  wrong result!
# paste(1  # comm, 7) 


# Tentative patch
unlockBinding("tidy.source", as.environment("package:formatR") )
assign("tidy.source", tidy.source.mod, pos="package:formatR")
environment(tidy.source)= asNamespace( "formatR" )

## Implementation with patch
tidy.source(text=text.input) # apparently ok:
# paste(1  # comm
# , 7)
```